# How to save values contains umlaut (ö) as cookies in JavaScript and then retrieve in Asp.Net MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies, model-view-controller

I am trying to set cookies in Javascript. The value contains Umlaut(ö). For example Köln from the script side. But it's saving as **K%F6ln**. And I can't retrieve Köln from the controller.
Any help will be appreciated :).
I already tried

```js
encodeURI("Köln") and encodeURIComponent("Köln")
```

But from the controller side, I always getting *K%F6ln**.

Comment: Your controller encoder is in a different format: [`encodeURIComponent` produces the "UTF-8 encoding of the character"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), not the character value. `'ö'` is `'\u00f6'`, but in its utf8 encoding, it takes two bytes, `0xc3b6`, which is what is then expected: `'%c3%b6'`. You could read it anyways, but not with `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Thanks, @ASDFGerte Any guidelines? how to overcome this issue?